# Creating a "through" relationship when both foreign keys are on the same table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `products` table. A `product` belongs to a `category` and a `country`.

I would like to find out what `countries` a `category` has by leaning on this relationship.

I've considered `hasManyThrough` and https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through but this is sort of a `belongsTo` relationship, with both foreign keys on an intermediate table, I suspect the `products` table is sort of acting like a pivot.

I would like to know how I can set up a relationship that relates `categories` to `countries` through the `products` table - is this possible?

#### Tables:

Categories

- id
- title

Countries

- id
- title

Products

- id
- title
- category_id
- country_id

#### Relationships:

A `product` belongs to a `country` / A `country` has many `products`.

A `product` belongs to a `category` / A `category` has many `products`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much described a Many to Many relationship with Product being the pivot table.

```php
# Category model
public function countries()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Country::class, 'products')
        ->withPivot(['id', 'title']); // optional
}
```

```php
# Country model
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'products')
        ->withPivot(['id', 'title']); // optional
}
```